# How to call the python variable into linux command

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am writing python script, in my python script i want to run "list of files in a directory" using commands.getoutput, my probleam is "i defined the directory path in python variable like "dir_name".I tried with following.

```
dir_name="/user/pjanga/python_test"
index_list=commands.getoutput('ls -l',dir_name,'| 'wc -l')
```

Error:-

```
File "diii.py", line 10
    index_list=commands.getoutput('ls -l',dir_name,'| 'wc -l')
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could you please help me out run?

Comment: I Think syntax highlighting says it all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems here, try:

```
index_list = commands.getoutput('ls -l ' + dir_name + ' | wc -l')
```

String concatenation is a `+`, not a comma, and you had an uneven number of single quotes.  Note also the space after the `ls -l`.

However, there are far better ways to do this.  First of all the answer does not represent the number of files in the directory.  Do an `ls -l` on the command-line and you will see that the first line is "total", not a filename (this is historical and represents the number of blocks, and is pretty useless).

If you used `ls` instead of `ls -l` you would not get this issue.

However, there is no need to call two separate external programs, use python:

```
import os
index_list = len([name for name in os.listdir(dir_name) ])
```

Here we call `os.listdir()` and create a list of filenames, then just get the number of items in that list.

There are several other ways to do this in python.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to execute the command from python in Linux machine.

Method 1:

```
index_list = commands.getoutput('ls -l ' + dir_name + ' | wc -l')
```

Method 2:

```
import os
os.system("ls -l ' + dir_name + ' | wc -l')
```

Method 3:

```
import subprocess
index_list = subprocess.check_output('ls -l ' + dir_name + ' | wc -l, shell=True)
```

Hope it helps !!